# How to Add/Filter Strings with <options> tag in html/php

Tags: php, html

```
   <select name="taskOption">
 <option value="<?php echo "$item_price "; ?>">
    <?php echo "$item_price [ Fruit Name] "; ?>
    </option>
</select>


 if (isset($_REQUEST['Button'])) {
        $selectOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
```

The above code workes fine.

I want to add one string with the value for filtration purpose.

```
   <select name="taskOption">


<option value="<?php echo "$item_price : Item_Name"; ?>">

    <?php echo "$item_price [ Fruit Name ] "; ?>
    </option>
</select>


 if (isset($_REQUEST['Button'])) {
        $selectOption = $_POST['taskOption'];
```

so that when  `<select name="taskOption">` is called it returns two values.
e.g

```
<option value="<?php echo "$item_price:Item_Name"; ?>">
```

> output   10:Item_Name

That i can seperate later using  explode.

Please help how to achieve this.
The Basic idea is to geet ITEM_PRICE and ITEM_NAME , That i can save into new variables and store into db

Comment: What's the problem with what you have?

Answer (score -1):

Try
 value="<?php echo $item_price . ':' . $Item_Name; ?>

I am writing from my phone. Sorry for any discrepancies